# SQL Reference multiple tables

Tags: sql, multiple-tables, referential-integrity

I want to define a mapping in SQL. The mapping is from one source table to several target tables. I'm using referential integrity, so if a value in the source table is deleted, the value in the mapping table should be deleted as well. The defination of the tables should look somehow like that:

```
-- Table with source members
Create Table dbo.Source_Members
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) Not Null,
    Name [nvarchar](50) Null
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Source_Members_Id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
        Id
    )
);
-- Table with target members
Create Table dbo.Target_Members1
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) Not Null,
    Name [nvarchar](50) Null,
    Target_Table_Id int DEFAULT 1
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Target_Members1_Id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
        Id, Target_Table_Id
    )
);
Create Table dbo.Target_Members2
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) Not Null,
    Name [nvarchar](50) Null,
    Target_Table_Id int DEFAULT 2
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Target_Members2_Id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
        Id, Target_Table_Id
    )
);
-- Mapping table
Create Table dbo.Mapping
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) Not Null,
    Id_Source_Members int Not Null,
    Id_Target_Members int Not Null,
    Target_Table_Id int Not Null
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Mapping] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
        Id
    )
);
-- Define first Foreign Key, referencing the source member (just one table)
Alter Table dbo.Mapping WITH CHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Source_Members] FOREIGN KEY (Id_Source_Members) REFERENCES dbo.Source_Members (Id)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
-- Define second Foreign Key, referencing the target member (several tables)
Alter Table dbo.Mapping WITH CHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Target_Members1] FOREIGN KEY (Id_Target_Members, Target_Table_Id) REFERENCES dbo.Target_Members1 (Id, Target_Table_Id)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
Alter Table dbo.Mapping WITH CHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Target_Members2] FOREIGN KEY (Id_Target_Members, Target_Table_Id) REFERENCES dbo.Target_Members2 (Id, Target_Table_Id)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

But this defination is not working. I would like to insert values in the mapping table like that:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Mapping(Id_Source_Members, Id_Target_Members, Target_Table_Id)
SELECT 1, 1, 1
UNION
SELECT 2, 1, 2
UNION
SELECT 3, 2, 2
```

Like that, the first source value should be mapped to the first value in Target_Members1. The second source value should be mapped to the first value in Target_Members2. The third source value should be mapped to the second value in Target_Members2 and so on. As I mentioned before, it's not working like that. How am I doing something like that, where is the failure?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert in multiple tables at once. You need separate SQL statements to do that.

So you will need:

```
INSERT INTO Source_Members(Name)
SELECT 'x'
UNION
SELECT 'y'
UNION
SELECT 'z'
;

INSERT INTO Target_Members1(Target_Table_Id)
SELECT 1
UNION
SELECT 2
;

INSERT INTO Target_Members2(Target_Table_Id)
SELECT 1
UNION
SELECT 2
;

INSERT INTO Mapping(Id_Source_Members, Id_Target_Members, Target_Table_Id)
SELECT 1, 1, 1
UNION
SELECT 3, 2, 2
;
```

Comment: I tried it like that before. If I do this:

`INSERT INTO dbo.Mapping(Id_Source_Members, Id_Target_Members, Target_Table_Id)
SELECT 1, 1, 1'

I got the error message "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Target_Members2". The conflict occurred in database "Hyperion_Staging", table "dbo.Target_Members2"."

If I do that:

`INSERT INTO dbo.Mapping(Id_Source_Members, Id_Target_Members, Target_Table_Id)
SELECT 2, 1, 2`

I got (as expected) the message: "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Target_Members1"..."

Comment: @elsmu: Did you fill that table too?

Comment: Yes: 
INSERT INTO dbo.Target_Members1(Name)
SELECT 'Target1_Member1'
UNION 
SELECT 'Target1_Member2'
UNION
SELECT 'Target1_Member3'

INSERT INTO dbo.Target_Members2(Name)
SELECT 'Target2_Member1'
UNION 
SELECT 'Target2_Member2'
UNION
SELECT 'Target2_Member3'

Comment: @elsmu: And what are the ID's? They should be matching the ones you use in your insert.

Comment: It's for both 1, 2, 3

Comment: @elsmu: The actual problem is in the last insert, second line. There is no match for those values in `Target1_Member1` (`SELECT 2, 1, 2`)

Comment: Sure there is, it's in "dbo.Target_Members2". I have to target member tables, that's what it is all about, because I want to do referental integrity with several tables.

Comment: I ran your script, and since there is a multi-column constraint on the  Mapping table, the second line fails since there is no matching line in the Target1_Member1 (the constraint points there, not to Target_Members2)

Comment: The constraint points to both tables, Target_Members1 and Target_Members2. Did you run the whole script?

Comment: Yes, I did. The problem is that it hits the first constraint: FK_Target_Members1. It has a foreign key constraint on both Id and Target_Table_Id of Target_Members1. There is no matching line in the example you gave.

Comment: OK, different approach. If I do that:
INSERT INTO dbo.Mapping(Id_Source_Members, Id_Target_Members, Target_Table_Id)
SELECT 1, 1, 1
I get the error "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Target_Members2". The conflict occurred in database "Hyperion_Staging", table "dbo.Target_Members2"."
In the source table, there is Id = 1, in the Target_Members1 table there is a ID = 1 / Target_Table_Id = 1. And this is working for you???

Comment: @elsmu: I updated the answer. This works for me on your script.

Comment: OK, now I got it. But this is not what I wanted to do. I need both entries in both tables, but I want every entry just unique either in one table or in the other one. In Target_Members1, I want the Target_Table_Id always to be 1, in Target_Members2, I want the Target_Table_Id always to be 2. So in the Mapping, I want to reference either the one target table (with 1, 1, 1 in the Mapping table,e I want to reference number 1 in Target_Members1) or the other. Do you know if / how i can do that?

Comment: @elsmu: If you mean you want to have this constraint OR the other constraint, no. There is no option to do that. Can't you merge those tables?

Comment: @elsmu: Need more help?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. Its two absolutely different tables, so merging them is no option. If there is no way to do so, I would even rather not implement the referental integrity.

Comment: @elsmu: You could create a post-update trigger to do the checking instead of the referential constraint.